RegEx to grab everything inside curly braces after finding a match
I have a really big text file that includes portions of text like this
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "startDate": "2024-12-10T18:45:00+01:00",
  "url": "https://www.gmail.com",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "Stadion Maksimir",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressLocality": "Zagreb",
      "addressCountry": "Croatia"
    }
  },
  "image": [
    "https://gmail.com"
  ],
  "description": "D. Zagreb at Stadion Maksimir"
  
}
</script>

and I'm trying to grab everything within the script tags (the dictionary). I've tried \"application/ld\+json\">^({.*})</script>  but this results in no matches.
I've tried \"application/ld\+json\">^({.*})</script>  but this results in no matches.

Generally a ^ means beginning of line, it does not mean or match a line-break. I have often used [\r\n]+ to match line breaks, but I do not know whether that will work in Python..
